# How to populate dropdown & radio using Backbone View

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am playing with Jquery Mobile along with Backbone. Have some scenario to populate the dropdown(select) when one of the radio (option) is selected.

View and markup can be viewed from here [partial code][1].  I am able to populate the dropdown on radio button selection changed event.

Now I like to know how to set these values on page load for the radio and select. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code link didn't work. It also may be better to just post the relevant bits directly into your question..

Comment: Basically on backbone render I want to set the values to Jquery Mobile Radio Button. Based on Radio button selection the subsequent select menu options to be rendered .